# Access 2010 VBA SQL INSERT with multiple SELECT

Tags: sql, vba

The following Code prompts out with, according to google, a kind of random/default error that doenst really lead to the problem. (Query input must contain at least one table or query)

```
Private Sub ButtonInsertUntergruppe_Click()
Dim sql As String

sql = "INSERT INTO tblArbeitsschritte (Auftrag_FK, Prozesspunkt_FK, Prozesspunkt) " & _
      "VALUES (" & _
                  Forms!frm_GUI!ID_Auftraege & _
                  ", " & _
                  "(SELECT ID_Prozesspunkt " & _
                  "FROM tblProzesspunkt " & _
                  "WHERE Untergruppe_FK = " & _
                  Me.cbUntergruppe.Column(0) & _
                  ") , " & _
                  "(SELECT Prozesspunkt " & _
                  "FROM tblProzesspunkt " & _
                  "WHERE Untergruppe_FK = " & _
                  Me.cbUntergruppe.Column(0) & _
                  "));"

Debug.Print sql
CurrentDb.Execute sql, dbFailOnError

End Sub
```

This is what the debugger gives me:

```
 INSERT INTO tblArbeitsschritt
    (
      Auftrag_FK, Prozesspunkt_FK, Prozesspunkt
    ) 
    VALUES 
    (
      1, 

      (SELECT ID_Prozesspunkt 
       FROM tblProzesspunkt 
       WHERE Untergruppe_FK = 1) 
      , 

      (SELECT Prozesspunkt 
       FROM tblProzesspunkt 
       WHERE Untergruppe_FK = 1)
    );
```

Comment: Uhhh. Wow. First post on stackoverflow and miserable failed on formatting. Trying to fix that. Sorry.

Comment: Is that syntax supported in Access SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that syntax is supported. Personally I would do:

```
 INSERT INTO tblArbeitsschritt
    (
      Auftrag_FK, Prozesspunkt_FK, Prozesspunkt
    ) 
    SELECT 1, ID_Prozesspunkt, Prozesspunkt 
    FROM tblProzesspunkt 
    WHERE Untergruppe_FK = 1
```